# could not resolve module

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

This is a generic Eclipse RCP application error and difficult to find root cause through searching.

Could not resolve module: pica.test.visit.rcp.todo [101]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.eavp.viz; bundle-version="0.1.1"

I'm following this tutorial with success:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#introduction-to-eclipse-rcp-applications

Running Eclipse ICE.
https://www.eclipse.org/ice/ 
ICE has the VisIT plugins installed for visualization calls under org.eclipse.eavp plugin

At 13.4.1. Add the plug-in dependencies: I add the org.eclipse.eavp.viz and org.eclipse.eavp.viz.service which causes above error.

What is the proper way to add such dependencies?

Answer (score -4):

*As updated by OP in an [edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44958625/2):*

---

At Step 13.4.1, do not add your plug-in dependencies. Instead create a target definition with the path to your plugin.

Right click your project > New > Other > Plug-in Development > Target Definition > Add > Path to Plugin > Save > Run

No errors, UI is shown.